# Quickfish automatic review

Tags: phantom, react, dapp

i am a new solana developer, and as new tester.

I trying to do a site that has a payment section button, that simply send an amout of sol to one wallet in exchange for digital credits to use my platform fatures.

When i develop at localhost... theres no problem all works,
but when i deploy into www i can see a AUTO ALERT after push buy button,
that it could be an scamm site, and contact to review@blowfish.xyz.

I send an email to try to get help, but for now i am reading about:

1. https://portal.blowfish.xyz/
2. https://phantom.app/learn/blog/security-at-phantom

i think that is for msg simulation maybe...

1. https://phantom.app/learn/blog/message-simulation

Also i am reading this:

1. https://docs.blowfish.xyz/docs/wallet-integration-guide

There are a snipped of the code of my React component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Transaction,SystemProgram,LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from "@solana/web3.js";

type PhantomEvent = "disconnect" | "connect" | "accountChanged";
interface ConnectOpts {onlyIfTrusted: boolean;}

interface PhantomProvider {
   connect: (opts?: Partial<ConnectOpts>) => Promise<{ publicKey: PublicKey }>;
   disconnect: ()=>Promise<void>;
   on: (event: PhantomEvent, callback: (args:any)=>void) => void;
   isPhantom: boolean;
   signTransaction: (transaction: Transaction) => Promise<Transaction>;
   publicKey: PublicKey;
}

interface Transaction{
   blockTime: number;
   confirmationStatus: string;
   signature: string;
   err: string;
   memo: string;
   slot: number;
}


type WindowWithSolana = Window & { solana?: PhantomProvider;}

export function Payments_Compo() {

const [ EwalletAvail, setWalletAvail ] = useState(false);
const [ Eprovider, setProvider ] = useState<PhantomProvider | null>(null);
const [ Econnected, setConnected ] = useState(false);
const [ EpubKey, setPubKey ] = useState<PublicKey | null>(null);
const [ Ebalance, setBalance ] = useState(0);
const [ EcsrfToken, setCsrfToken] = useState('');
const [ Econnection, setConnection ] = useState<Connection| null>(null);
const [ ElasTx, setLastTx ] = useState<String| null>(null); //last transaction

//db
const [ Einfowallet, setInfoWallet ] = useState<any | null>(null);
const [ Edeposwallet, setDeposWallet ] = useState<any | null>(null);


function setDevnetConnection(){
    setConnection(new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet")));
}

useEffect( ()=> {
    if ("solana" in window) {
        const solWindow = window as WindowWithSolana;
        if (solWindow?.solana?.isPhantom) {
            setProvider(solWindow.solana);
            setWalletAvail(true);
            // Attempt an eager connection
            solWindow.solana.connect({ onlyIfTrusted: true });
        }
        setDevnetConnection();
    }
}, []);

useEffect( () => {
    if (Eprovider !== null){
    Eprovider.on("connect", (publicKey: PublicKey)=>{ 
        //console.log(`connect event: ${publicKey}`);
        setConnected(true); 
        setPubKey(publicKey);
        
    })} 

    Eprovider?.on("disconnect", ()=>{ 
        //console.log("disconnect event");
        setConnected(false); 
        setPubKey(null);
    });

    
    Econnected? getInfoWallet_blockchain() : console.log("No connected yet");
    Econnected && Eprovider? getInfowallet_DB(Eprovider.publicKey.toString()): 
    console.log("No connected yet");
    Econnected && Eprovider? getdeposWallet_DB(Eprovider.publicKey.toString()): 
    console.log("No connected yet");

}, [Eprovider,Econnected,ElasTx,EcsrfToken]); 


function connectHandler(): void {
    console.log(`connect handler`);
    Eprovider?.connect()
    .catch((err:any) => { console.error("connect ERROR:", err); });
}

function disconnectHandler(): void {
    console.log("disconnect handler");
    Eprovider?.disconnect()
    .catch((err:any) => {console.error("disconnect ERROR:", err); });
}


async function transferSOL() {
    //var provider = await getProvider(); //wallet conectada
    
    if (Eprovider && Econnection){
        setLastTx(null)
        const provider = Eprovider;
        //provider? console.log("Public key of the emitter: ",provider.publicKey.toString()) : console.log("No provider available");

        var recieverWallet = new PublicKey("receiverwallet***");
        
        var transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: provider.publicKey,
            toPubkey: recieverWallet,
            lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL/5 //Investing 1 SOL. Remember 1 Lamport = 10^-9 SOL.
            }),
        );

        //console.log(transaction)

        // Setting the variables for the transaction           
        let blockhashObj = await Econnection.getRecentBlockhash();
        transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;
        transaction.feePayer = await provider.publicKey;
    
        if(transaction) {console.log("Txn created successfully");}
        console.log("[TXPAY][1] WORKING GOOD")

        // Request creator to sign the transaction (allow the transaction)
        let signed = await provider.signTransaction(transaction);
        let txhash_signatures = await Econnection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize()); //sendTX
        
        let confirm = await Econnection.confirmTransaction(txhash_signatures);
        console.log("[TXPAY][2] txhash: ", txhash_signatures);
        //console.log("Confirm1: ", confirm); //no me da nada significativo
        
    }
}
```

But if somebody can give some help i would appreciate to much!!!

[image: After transaction pays happend]

Comment: It might be best to reach out to Phantom or Blowfish directly, I don't think they provide support here unfortunately